# Slicing arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How could I slice an array with another boolean array in PHP?

```
<?php

$arr=array(0=>12,1=>'name',2=>1.21,4=>'color');
$select=array(1=>true,2=>true,3=>true,4=>false);

//$new=$arr[$select];

?>
```

In Python this is simple, but can I do this also in PHP?

Comment: Using [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) perhaps?

Comment: So you want to keep the elements from `$arr` where the corresponding key => value in `$select` is true?

Comment: @Mark Baker the function array_slice() takes only one array as argument.. but I have two arrays.

Comment: @Rizier123 yes, exactly

Comment: exactly what are you trying to get out of this code? an intersection of the two arrays?  or do those booleans signify something?

Comment: @Andy Look up `array_intersect_key()` + `array_filter()` for `$select` which you need to filter first.

Comment: If you have PHP 5.6+ you can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY`

Comment: So any progress made here? Did the above function helped you?

Comment: thanks! the two function seem to do the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines return the associative array that I want:

```
$filter=array_filter($select);
$new=array_intersect_key($arr,$filter);
var_dump($new);
```